# How to update a global variable used in a function but updated in other one?

Tags: julia, global-variables

I have the following code in Julia

```
global a::Int = 0 #global variable

function f(x)
      return a*x
end

function g(y)
      global a = 2
      b = f(2)
      return b
end
```

It is not the exact code but the idea is the same. In this sketch of code, when it is calculated f(2) in g(y), the value of a used is the original a = 0, and not the updated value a = 2. Do you know how can I fix this problem?

I try to pass a as a parameter and it works, but I would like to keep the function f without extra parameter as inputs.

Comment: Global variables are almost always a bad idea performance wise, and almost always avoidable. I'd recommend that you try to solve your problem without a global variable.

Comment: g(0) yields 4. What other value would you expect? (BTW remove colons from your code)

Answer (score 0):

Given the case where a a global variable is necessary, your code, edited for syntax and with print lines, appears to be functional. To Check this, write the global variable, `GLOBALVAR`'s  before and after it's reassignment in `g(...)`.

```
#set the global variable to zero.
global GLOBALVAR = Int(0)

#f(x) references the global variable, but doesn't modify it.
function f(x)
      return GLOBALVAR*x
end

#g(x) modifies the global variable.
function g(y)
      global GLOBALVAR = 2
      b = f(2)
      return b
end

println("Before g(x) call: \n GLOBALVAR = $GLOBALVAR \n f(2) = $(f(2))")
g(2);
println("After g(x) call: \n GLOBALVAR = $GLOBALVAR \n f(2) = $(f(2))")

julia>
Before g(x) call: 
 GLOBALVAR = 0
 f(2) = 0
After g(x) call:
 GLOBALVAR = 2
 f(2) = 4
```

The global variable has been updated.

Global variables can get you into some trouble. They are often less readable, and sometimes less performant. We potentially want to refactor to exclude their use.

One notable difference is that numbers are *not mutable* in julia. A function like

```
function setToZero!(n::Int)
   n = 0
   return n
end

num = 10
println("before: $num")
setToZero!(num)
println("after: $num")

julia>
before: 10
after: 10
```

is unable to act as intended, because assigning n does not mutate the original variable. There are many mutable types, and a simple workaround is that the values in a Vector *are mutable.* Keep in mind there are many solutions, like `Ref`'s or creating new mutable structs entirely. With that, we can refactor your original code with:

```
f(x, val::Vector) = val[1]*x

function g!(y, val::Vector)
    val[1] = 2
    return f(2, val)
end

changingVal = [0]

println("Before g!(...) call: \n changingVal = $changingVal \n f(2,changingVal) = $(f(2,changingVal))")
g!(2, changingVal);
println("Before g!(...) call: \n changingVal = $changingVal \n f(2,changingVal) = $(f(2,changingVal))")

julia>
Before g!(...) call: 
 changingVal = [0]
 f(2,changingVal) = 0
Before g!(...) call:
 changingVal = [2]
 f(2,changingVal) = 4
```

Of course, creating a vector is going to be less space and time efficient that just creating a single global Int, so in this simplified example, the "non-global" version will be *significantly* slower. This may or may not be true in larger programs, but both ways are valid.